# Adding promise to DomOutline event handler

Tags: javascript, dom, asynchronous, promise

The asynchronous function I am trying to call is defined by `onClick` property of [DomOutline](https://github.com/andrewchilds/jQuery.DomOutline/blob/master/jquery.dom-outline-1.0.js). For this example, `domClickHandler` is like callback that receives the selected element.

```
    var iWantThis;

    var myDomOutline = DomOutline({
        onClick: domClickHandler,
        filter: false,
        stopOnClick: true,
        hideLabel: true
    });

    var domClickHandler = function(element){
        iWantThis = element
        console.log("I am the element you've selected: " + element);
    };

    myDomOutline.start();
    console.log("From the outside world: " + iWantThis);
    return iWantThis;
```

`DomOutline.start()` returns right away and `domClickHandler` is asynchronous callback. So in this example, the last `console.log` will return undefined even before I select the element. I have tried trying `$.when()` on a function that wraps around `DomOutline.start()` to return `promise()`, but it didn't make the async call synchronous. What is the way to use promise here so that I could return the DOM object when it has been selected?

I promisified the callback, but I am not sure how this will help me to achieve synchronous return of the array `iWantThis`

```
var domClikcHandler= function(element){
        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        classifiedElements = __classifyChildrenElements(element);
        dfd.resolve(classifiedElements);
        dfd.then(function(e){
            console.log(e);
            iWanThis = e;
        });
        return dfd.promise()
    };
```

Comment: You are expecting promises to do something that they do not. A promise is an abstraction of a value, not something that converts an asynchronous process to synchronous. You probably want to [convert your existing callback api to promises](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises). Once achieved, DomOutline's `onClick` callback will feed a promise, and you can pass a callback to promise method `.then()`.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I can convert the callback `domClickHandler` to return a promise, but your last sentence is not clear to me. Where would I put the chaining of of `.then()`?

Comment: Read the linked Q/A.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I have updated the question to add the changes, but I am still not clear how I can return the array within the callback. Other than going into some client-server model, is there a way for me to achieve this. If promise is not the right direction, could you refer me another approach?

Comment: Forethinker, you're still missing the point - you can't handle asynchronous processes synchronously. Whether you use promises or not, the response of an asynchronous process must be handled in a callback. With promises, the only thing that changes is the object to which that callback is passed.

Comment: Besides, an onClick handler isn't a candidate for promisification, as it will get called many times and a promise can only ever be resolved/rejected once. Your only realistic option is to do whatever is necessary with `element` inside the callback. Don't try to address it in the "outside world".

Comment: @Roamer-1888 well, with the exception of generators.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder @BenjaminGruenbaum. For Forethinker's benefit, "generators" are something that will be introduced into Ecmascript (javascript) at some later edition.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take this one step at a time.

### What a promise is

A promise an abstraction over the notion of value - it represents a value + time. Operations you perform on it queue and will happen when the time comes.

A promise starts off as **pending** and then goes through  **resolution** to become either:

- **fulfilled** - meaning it is available for use and chaining.
- **rejected** - meaning that the operation failed and you can attempt to recover from it

In libraries that are not jQuery and in native promises - the transition process as well as the execution of handlers is always *asynchronous*. This is in order to prevent race conditions in cases it *might* be asynchronous.

### What a promise is not

**A promise is not an event emitter** - you cannot bind a promise to an event that happens more than once since it represents a single value. The dual of promises that represents multiple values is called an [Observable](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS#about-the-reactive-extensions). You cannot bind a promise to a click event.

**A promise is not magic** - it is usually implemented in JavaScript, it cannot convert asynchronous code to synchronous code, while its `then` abstracts the notion of sequencing itself - it cannot without language support 'stop' code on asynchronous operation in order for that other language facilities are required like generators (ES6) or async/await (ES7). For most browser users who don't want to go through [a compile step](https://facebook.github.io/regenerator/) promises can make your life easier but not make asynchronous code synchronous.

In general promises use return values and thrown exceptions for well... return values and thrown exceptions. A promise resolves *once* with a single value just like a value has just one value and once you have obtained it it does not change.

### How to use promises

In you case the click handler *fundamentally* can't be modeled with promises - it requires an event emitter aka observable. What you have with the `onBtnClick` looks just fine.

In the case of the `ready` event - assuming you [promisified it correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) (calling `$.when` doesn't help on its own) you need to chain to it:

```
 myDomOutline.start().then(function(){
     alert("Ready!");
 });
```

If you want to access it from the outside that's just fine since promises compose:

```
function startWithData(){
     var request = $.ajax(...);
     return myDomOutline.start().then(function(){ // note the return
         startAnimations();
         doAnotherThing();
         return request; // return the request
     });
}

startWithData().then(function(data){
    // ajax done and ready event fired
    // access data here
});
```

As additional reading please see [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call/) which is not promise centric but still very relevant.